# How to compare data where data matches (or doesn't match) on two columns?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I apologize if this is answered somewhere, but I'm only seeing questions regarding matching one to one columns. I'll provide an example of what I'm looking for...

If I have a sheet with this data:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
  1    ...    1    ...    a
  1    ...    2    ...    b
  1    ...    3    ...    c
  2    ...    1    ...    a
  2    ...    3    ...    c
```

and a second sheet with this data:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
   1    ...    1    ...    a
   1    ...    2    ...    b
   2    ...    1    ...    a
   2    ...    3    ...    c
```

And I want to compare the two sheets to find where Column 1 + 3 in sheet 1 don't match with Column 1 + 3 in sheet 2. So I would see (through marking rows that match with "match" or a color, or something similar,) that the row "1 ... 3 ... C" doesn't exist in the second sheet.

I can try to explain further if needed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may need a helper column, such that column 4 would be `=A1&B1&C1` resulting in `D1` as `11a`. 

You could then `COUNTIF` in Sheet1 Column E: `=COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$1:$D$4,'Sheet1'!$D1)`

Or, to expand `=IF(COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$D$1:$D$4,'Sheet1'!$D1)>0,"MATCH","")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional formatting with the below formula and choose a color to highlight the unique rows.

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10,$A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10,$B1,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10,$C1)=0
```

Range A1:A10 is the range of your data. You can modify it as per your need. 
Once you select the color for formatting, excel highlights the row "1 3 C" alone. Let me know if you need anything more. You should be doing this formatting in Sheet1